# "Unexpected error" when a page is checked out 

Tags: 2007, error, check-out

I am facing a strange issue now. If a page is checked out by someone all others who view this page gets an "Unexpected error" error page.

After making some changes to web.config I was able to get the stack trace. Any idea how to solve this issue? This issue started recently after installing an additional language pack but I doubt whether that is the reason for the error.

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager.get_m_Site() +101
   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager.get_IsSiteAdmin() +94
   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager..ctor(ServerContext serverContext, Boolean IgnoreUserPrivacy, Boolean backwardCompatible) +585
   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager..ctor(ServerContext serverContext) +85
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ConsoleUtilities.GetPageCheckedOutMessage(String userLoginName, String userName, String userEmail) +1527
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ConsoleDataSource.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +1617
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +107
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +223
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +223
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +223
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +223
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +223
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +223
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +223
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +223
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +223
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +223
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3393
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen when anyone checks out the document, or just a specific user?

If it's a specific user that's causing this issue for all others, could be profile corruption.

Answer (score 0):

Is the user profile visible to all users?
Could be that Sharepoint isn't able to resolve some user properties because the other users don't have enough permissions to view them.
Off-course a corrupted profile is possible also.

Hmm, it appears the null-reference appears in the get_m_Site() method.
You could try to check out the user his/her personal site. It could be the user has made some information unavailable to other users which is needed when 'viewing' the account.